# How to turn off auto changing of words in reports like Height, Width and Count in Access 2000

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2000

For a (old) project I created a report in Access 2000. In this report I wanted to create a field that multiplies 3 table fields values, namely: Aantal, Hoogte and Breedte.

So I put it in my text field the following: `=[Hoogte] * [Breedte] * [Aantal]`.
The language of my Access 2000 is Dutch.

What happens is that Access automatically changed those 3 words to respectively `[Height] * [Width] * [Count]`. Obviously the field doesn't recognize these table fields since they aren't named like that.

The problem is that those 3 Dutch words (Hoogte, Breedte, Aantal) mean Height, Width and Count in English. So I guess Access thinks I want to use those (which I don't). '

The question is, how can I stop this auto filling/correcting/translating of these words? Is there a setting to turn it off?

I already looked in options--->general tab--->Auto name correction but everything was already turned off in here (except Keep/record information).

Comment: Do you want you  calculated field in a query, form or report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height, Width and Count are reserved words in Access VBA so using them is going to cause you problems.  If you are working in a form  try changing the text [Form]![Height]+[Form]![Width]+[Form]![Count] and for a report do the same except with [Report]![Height]+[Report]![Width]+[Report]![Count].  It's hard to test this without changing my language.  Hmmm, what if you removed Dutch as your language?